# Dockerizing python project Dockerfile creation

Tags: docker, dockerfile

This question is asked before yet After reviewing the answers I am still not able to copy the solution.

I am still new to docker and after watching tutorials and following articles I was able to create a Dockerfile for an existing GitHub repository.

I started by using the nearest available image as a base then adding what I need.

from what I read the problem is in **WORKDIR** and **CMD** commands
This is error message:

> python: can't open file 'save_model.py': [Errno 2] No such file or directory*

This is my Dockerfile:

```
# syntax=docker/dockerfile:1

FROM tensorflow/serving:2.3.0-rc0-devel-gpu

WORKDIR app

COPY requirements-gpu.txt .

# install dependencies
RUN pip install -r requirements-gpu.txt

# copy the content of the local src directory to the working directory
COPY /home/pc/Desktop/yolo4_deep .

# command to run on container start
CMD ["python","./app/save_model.py","./app/object_tracker.py" ]
```

1. src

   - save_model.py
   - object_tracker.py
   - ...
2. requirements.txt
3. Dockerfile

I tried WORKDIR command to set the absolute path: `WORKDIR /home/pc/Desktop/yolo4_Deep_sort_nojupitor` the result was Same Error.

[image: Folder hierarchy]

Comment: You need to `COPY` the python files to the docker image.

Comment: ...and the `COPY` path is _always_ relative to the `docker build` context directory, usually the directory containing the Dockerfile.  You cannot use an absolute host-system path there and it will be interpreted as `./home/pc/...` which probably isn't what you want.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks for help Everyone.
As I mentioned earlier I'm beginner in the docker world. I solved the issue by editing the copy command.

```
    # syntax=docker/dockerfile:1

FROM tensorflow/serving:2.3.0-rc0-devel-gpu

WORKDIR /home/pc/Desktop/yolo4_deep

COPY requirements-gpu.txt .

# install dependencies
RUN pip install -r requirements-gpu.txt

# copy the content of the local src directory to the working directory
COPY src/ .

# command to run on container start
ENTRYPOINT ["./start.sh"]
```

Answer (score 0):

I see multiple issues in your Dockerfile.

1. `COPY /home/pc/Desktop/yolo4_deep .`

   The `COPY` command copies files from your local machine to the container. The path on your local machine must be path relative to your build context. The build context is the path you pass in when you run `docker build .` — in this case the `.` (the current directory) is the build context. Also the local machine path can only reference files located under the build context — i.e. paths containing `..` (parent directory) or `/` (root directory) are not allowed.
2. `WORKDIR app`

   `WORKDIR` sets the path inside the container not on your local machine. So `WORKDIR /app`  means that all commands — `RUN`, `CMD`, `ENTRYPOINT` — will be executed from the `/app` directory.
3. `CMD ["python","./app/save_model.py","./app/object_tracker.py" ]`

   As mentioned above `WORKDIR /app` causes all operations to be executed from the `/app` directory. So `./app/save_model.py` is actually translated as `/app/app/save_model.py`.

Comment: Thanks! everything you said is true. I'm still beginner in docker. I was able to solve the error.
moreover from what I undestand in docker cmd you can't launch two python scripts. so I added a simple bash script that launches the two files.